# $1/2 = 1 - e^{-n(n-1)/2d}$ General Birthday Formula?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, quadratic-forms, birthday

When solving $\frac{1}{2} = 1 - e^{-n(n-1)/2d}$ for $n$, the solution should be  $n \approx \sqrt{\ln(4)d}$. But I can't get the calculations done.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

PS: The formula has to do with the General Birthday Formula and it simply states the 50% chance that at least 2 people (among $n$ people) share the same birthday when there are $d$ days.

Comment: Try solving $\frac{1}{2} = 1 - e^{-n^2/2d}$ or $\frac{1}{2} = e^{-n^2/2d}$ or $-\log_e(2) = -n^2/2d$ or  $2d\log_e(2) = n^2$ or $n=\sqrt{d \log_e(4)}$

Comment: Then note that $\frac{1}{2} = 1 - e^{-(n-1)^2/2d}$ would give $n=1+\sqrt{d \log_e(4)}$ so perhaps $\frac{1}{2} = 1 - e^{-n(n-1)/2d}$ suggests $n=\frac12+\sqrt{d \log_e(4)}$ might be a better approximation, and you can in fact do even better than that

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you are right the trick is in $n^2 \approx n(n-1)$ when $n$ is large.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{1}{2} = 1 - e^{ - n(n - 1)/2d}  \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2} = e^{ - n(n - 1)/2d}  \Leftrightarrow \log 2 = \frac{{n(n - 1)}}{{2d}}
$$
$$
 \Rightarrow 2d\log 2 = n(n - 1) \approx n^2  \Rightarrow n \approx \sqrt {2d\log 2}  = \sqrt {d\log 4} .
$$
Note that since
$$
n(n - 1) = \left( {n - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)^2  - \tfrac{1}{4}
$$
we have in fact
$$
n = \tfrac{1}{2} + \sqrt {\tfrac{1}{4}+d\log 4}.
$$